# Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() with WAMP

Tags: php, sql, driver, wamp

I know that this question has already been asked several times on this website but I'm seriously starting to wonder wheter I'm crazy or not.

My configuration : WampServer 2.5 64bits (PHP 5.5.12, Apache 2.4.9)

My steps:

1. Download Microsoft Driver SQLSRV32.exe from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
2. Extract the files from the .exe downloaded on my desktop
3. Copy *php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll* and *php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll* into *C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext*
4. Edit *C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini* adding "*extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll*" and "*extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll*"
5. Edit *C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini* adding "*extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll*" and "*extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll*"
6. Restart all services (I even tried to restart my computer, but nothing works)

I still get the error... So what am I missing to make this work ?

Comment: I have exactly same setup. 

I just had to add it to C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini , and since i was only using sqlsrv_connect, only used php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll, but i guess pdo extension would not hurt.

Please note that nothing else worked.. 53/54/56 ... or 7_ts_x86/x64

Answer (score 2):

Installing just the PHP extension is not enough, you also need to install Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server® - Windows

[The ODBC drivers can be found here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)

And [newer drivers can be found here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098)

Also the best way to ensure you are editing the correct `php.ini` file is to use the wampmanager menus. So in future do :-

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> php.ini
```

This will load the correct php.ini into yoru editor.

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php{version}\php.ini` is used only by PHP CLI

`C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin\php.ini` is used only by PHP when running under Apache

Answer (score 2):

I finally found what was causing the problem. My Wamp was in 64 bits but the sqlsrv driver only works with 32 bits version. Now it works perfectly.

Comment: It was the only issue for me. +1 from me.

Comment: @qwertzuiop how did you fix it? I am having the same issue. Please help

Comment: @YunusAslam Download the 32 bits version of Wamp

Comment: @qwertzuiop I got it working with 64bit itself. Just used the correct dll file.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to modify php.ini using the wamp interface ?

I know it sounds strange but sometimes the result is different than editing directly the file using the browser. Wamp manages those files in a strange way, give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

Detailed steps for SQL Server Lovers to Install and Configure PhP:

1. Install Wamp wampserver2.5-Apache-2.4.9-Mysql-5.6.17-php5.5.12-32b.exe
2. Configure PhP
   a. Update conf file 
       Thumbrules are
           i. Change Port
           ii. Change from Deny to Granted
           iii. Change from None to Allow
           iii. Change the order from Deny, Allow to Allow, Deny

   ```
   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf
   Line # 62, 63
   Listen 127.0.0.1:8201
   Listen [::0]:8201

   Line # 240
   <Directory />
       AllowOverride all
       #Require all granted
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>

   Line #274
   AllowOverride all

   Line #282
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   Line #299
   Require all granted
   ```

   b. If Wamp is running, exit and restart
   c. type http://localhost:8201/ in browser, to get wamp home page
   d. place any sample html page in c:\wamp\www folder
       http://localhost:8201/pagename.html
3. SSSP, create a Directory - project name, keep .zip file, config.xml, sssp_config.xml, widgets.ino files in this folder
       http://hostname:8201/DirectoryName in URL Launcher to install Widgets in SSSP TV
       Read SSSP Configuration file for more details on SSSP
4. SQL Server Configuration
   Current Configuration
       WampServer 2.5 32bits  [64 bits success story for SQL Server is less]
       PHP 5.5.12
       Apache 2.4.9

   ```
   Steps:

   a. Download Microsoft Driver SQLSRV32.exe from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098. 
   b. Extract the files from the .exe downloaded on my temp folder
   c. Copy php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll and php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll into C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext folder
   d. Or Copy dlls from DLL folder to C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext folder
   e. Edit C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.ini add
       extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
       extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
   f. Edit C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\bin\php.ini add 
       extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
       extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
   g. Install Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 64 bit or 32 bit as per your OS. My OS is 64 bit. The ODBC drivers can be found @ https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434 or in the folder ODBC
       And newer drivers can be found @ https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
   e. Restart all services / Restart computer
   f. Place Sample php files in c:\wamp\www\TestWeb folder and browse http://localhost:8201/TestWeb/page.php
   g. Change host name, db name, uid and pwd as per your SQL server credentials
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use php_error.log ( `wamp->php->php error log` ).

And `php_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll`, `php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_ts_x64.dll` is working with the 7.0.29 version of PHP, but **not** with 7.2.4.

And Restart of Services is not enough, exit and run Wamp.

Answer (score 0):

It'll work with 64 or 32 bits just download the right dll file for your operating system and update your php.ini file.